# Is it possible to know the mother address of a subnet?

Tags: subnet

The mother address is X, have Y numbers of subnets (children), we already know 2 of the mother's children, they're:

10.1.192.0 /20  [edited]

10.1.240.0 /20

Is it possible to know the value of X and Y according to the given details?

I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: BTW, apologizes to your mother, but the correct term is “supernet.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can calculate the smallest `supernet` that contains 2 given networks (or any number of networks).

The easiest way to do this is in binary (yes really):

First convert your two addresses in binary:

10.1.192.0 = 00001010.00000001.11000000.00000000
10.1.240.0 = 00001010.00000001.11110000.00000000

As you can see, the part that is common to this two addresses is 00001010.00000001.11 which is 18 bits long.

So we now we are looking for a /18 network.

To get the network address we take those 18 bits and complete to 32 bits with trailing zeros and we get:

00001010.00000001.11000000.00000000 /18 = **10.1.192.0 /18**

Now to calculate your Y value, assuming subnet of equal size, i.e. /20, this boil down to "how many /20 subnet do we have in a /18 network".

To calculate this we the take the size difference and square it.

20 - 18  = 2
2^2 = 4 = Y
=> we have 4 /20 subnets.

Comment: While your arithmetic is sound, you can't know whether a supernet actually *exists* (ie. whether it is administrated by a single entity) or if it is (much) larger even.

Comment: @Zac67, from a pure IP perspective, a supernet always exist, up to 0.0.0.0/0 (or ::/0). Regarding the administration, well, that's a totally different question.